# Multiple edge colors/style for a FE mesh in paraview

Tags: paraview

Hi everyone,

Is there a way in which I can change the color/style of particular edge of a mesh in paraview?

For example: In the attached image, I would like the right edge to be of different style (dotted) or of different color. [FE Mesh composed of four T3 elements.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0iKH.png)

This obviously is a simple mesh. I also have complex meshes where I would like to select some edges manually from the GUI and color them or change their style.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, no. As of ParaView 5.3, this is not supported.